bypass dns to get SSL certificate via python standard ssl and socket modules
I have existing code that pulls a SSL cert via ssl.get_server_certificate and it works fine, but I'm needing to bypass DNS and send a request to serverA.fqdn to get the certificate for siteB.fqdn on serverA. This is Python 3.12 on Fedora 40 connecting to a Apache server that only supports TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3.
I only need to pull the SSL cert and get some metadata from it (SANs and the issue and expiration dates). I have no need to do a full HTTP request.
I have some test code just to hash it out that looks like this:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import pprint, socket, ssl


context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)

#context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
#context.minimum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_2
#context.maximum_version = ssl.TLSVersion.TLSv1_3

sock = socket.socket()
conn = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname="hostA.fqdn")
conn.connect(("siteB.fqdn", 443))

cert = conn.getpeercert()

pprint.pprint(cert)

based on the code in the python.org docs for SSL connections as a client.
I've tried this with both the "create_default_context" and the manual context creation and both ways I get the error:
sl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl/tls alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1000)

If I'm reading that error right then it's trying to do a SSLv3 handshake. All the docs seem to indicate that the default should be TLS "auto" for the best available if you use the defaults. The ssl.get_server_certificate sets a default context from what I can tell and it works fine (ie: my CA file and "trust" setup is fine).
What am I missing?

If you want to bypass DNS, put the IP address instead of siteB.fqdn in conn.connect().

"siteB" is the SSL cert I want to fetch though. It's a SNI enabled server. I thought "server_hostname" would be the "IP" that is resolved to connect to and the .connect would be the "site" to connect to???

server_hostname is a virtual server hostname, related to the Host: header in the HTTP connection, and it uses that when validating the certificate. The IP to connect to comes from looking up the name in conn.connect() using DNS.

Dogh. So, I just had them backwards. Thanks. Appreciate the response. It works when I flip them.

Barmar pointed out my mistake in comments. I just needed to flip my values for the connect and server_hostname calls.
